# Revit API: How can I count total point on the edge of the floor?

Tags: c#, revit-api

As my title, I want to know total endpoint located on the edge of the floor. Does anyone has a solution?
My ideal maybe like this:

```
int i = 0;
FilteredElementCollector docCollector1 = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(Point));
foreach(Point point in docCollector1)
{
  i++;
}
TaskDialog.Show("Revit","Have total {0} point on the edge of the floor ", i);
```

This's image about my problem:
[Edge has endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwQ7.png)

I only wan't to know how many endpoint arround my floor.

I can identify 4 edge by this code, but I'm still don't know get all the point for each edge.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ea.Size; i++)
{
    Edge e = ea.get_Item(i);
        //Identify point located edge in here       
    IList<XYZ> exyz = e.Tessellate();
    int m = exyz.Count;
    XYZ sPoint = exyz[0];
    XYZ ePoint = exyz[m - 1];
    XYZ mPoint = new XYZ((sPoint.X + ePoint.X) / 2, (sPoint.Y + ePoint.Y) / 2, 0);          
}
```

Comment: You should add detailed problem description - what is expected results, what do you have actually? some error description if there is an error. And of course you should add code required to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1):

I just answered your question on [how to get all the points on the edge of the floor](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-can-get-all-the-point-on-the-edge-of-the-floor/m-p/7155217) in the [Revit API discussion forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/bd-p/160):

You can add a geometric location filter, e.g., using a [BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/1fbe1cff-ed94-4815-564b-05fd9e8f61fe.htm).

Here are some examples:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/03/filter-for-family-instances-in-a-room.html

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.9